# Why does a custom control "ImageButton" not display it's image?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm writing an image button custom control with highlighting effects, based on MahApps' AccentedSquareButtonStyle. **ImageButton.xaml**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NQR_GUI_WPF.ImageButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NQR_GUI_WPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" >
<Button Style="{StaticResource AccentedSquareButtonStyle}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="24" Height="24" TouchDown="Button_TouchDown">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding HighlightedImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding ClickedImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContentControl.Style>
        </ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

**ImageButton.xaml.cs**:

```
namespace NQR_GUI_WPF
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for ImageButton.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ImageButton : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(Canvas), typeof(ImageButton));
    public static DependencyProperty ClickedImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ClickedImage", typeof(Canvas), typeof(ImageButton));
    public static DependencyProperty HighlightedImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightedImage", typeof(Canvas), typeof(ImageButton));

    static ImageButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ImageButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ImageButton)));
    }

    public Canvas Image
    {
        get { return (Canvas)base.GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public Canvas ClickedImage
    {
        get { return (Canvas)base.GetValue(ClickedImageProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(ClickedImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public Canvas HighlightedImage
    {
        get { return (Canvas)base.GetValue(HighlightedImageProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(HighlightedImageProperty, value); }
    }

    private void Button_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Keyboard.ClearFocus();
    }
}
```

}

Example icon:

```
<Canvas x:Key="printIcon" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_printer_text" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
            <Path Width="44" Height="45" Canvas.Left="16" Canvas.Top="17" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=theme, Converter={StaticResource idealForegroundConverter}}" Data="F1 M 25,27L 25,17L 51,17L 51,27L 47,27L 47,21L 29,21L 29,27L 25,27 Z M 16,28L 60,28L 60,51L 52,51L 52,46L 55,46L 55,33L 21,33L 21,46L 24,46L 24,51L 16,51L 16,28 Z M 25,39L 28,39L 28,52L 35,52L 35,59L 48,59L 48,39L 51,39L 51,62L 33,62L 25,54L 25,39 Z M 46,55L 38,55L 38,52L 46,52L 46,55 Z M 46,49L 30,49L 30,46L 46,46L 46,49 Z M 46,43L 30,43L 30,40L 46,40L 46,43 Z "/>
        </Canvas>
```

The problem is that in MainWindow, after adding the images stored in App.xaml, the control is empty (no images are shown).

```
<local:ImageButton Image="{StaticResource printIcon}" HighlightedImage="{StaticResource printIconHighlighted}" ClickedImage="{StaticResource printIconClicked}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="46" Margin="36,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

I have tried binding the images directly into the control template, but without success (although in the control designer view the image is shown). **Why aren't the control images displayed?**

Comment: have you tried {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
 AncestorType={x:Type local:ImageButton}}, Path=Image}, it's the syntax with x:type specified

Comment: For the record, it is not a very good idea to have your DependencyProperties be UserControls like you are using `Canvas` for your `Image` properties. UserControls can only be assigned to one parent in the UI, so if any other control tries to add the `Canvas` `printIcon`, it will throw an exception. I would recommend either switching to using Images, or use a Template instead. A `Template` is like a cookie-cutter - anytime it needs to render, it will create whatever the templated controls are. This way, you never run into the problem of two controls trying to access the same Canvas instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UserControl` isn't your best option for this. UserControls aren't meant for writing general-purpose WPF controls. You can do it, but it's not the simplest way. The simplest way is to subclass a regular control (often just `ContentControl` or `HeaderedContentControl`), then write a style and a template for it. Once you get this technique nailed down you can just bang 'em out as needed. Often you can just write a specialized template for an existing control, but in your case you do need your own subclass of `Button`.

I would write `ImageButton` as a subclass of `Button`, with the additional dependency properties pretty much as you've defined them, but I'd make them of type `Object` so a consumer can stuff anything in there that XAML can render. No reason not to give them all the rope they can use. And I'll use the `Content` property instead of the `Image` property, because that simplifies things.

If for some reason you have a requirement to prevent non-image content, you could use a more specialized content type than `Object`, but you didn't mention any particular reason for introducing that limitation.

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace NQR_GUI_WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ImageButton.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public class ImageButton : Button
    {
        public ImageButton()
        {
            TouchDown += ImageButton_TouchDown;
        }

        private void ImageButton_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            Keyboard.ClearFocus();
        }

        #region Dependency Properties
        public static DependencyProperty ClickedContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ClickedContent", typeof(Object), typeof(ImageButton));
        public static DependencyProperty HighlightedContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightedContent", typeof(Object), typeof(ImageButton));

        public Object ClickedContent
        {
            get { return (Object)base.GetValue(ClickedContentProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(ClickedContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public Object HighlightedContent
        {
            get { return (Object)base.GetValue(HighlightedContentProperty); }
            set { base.SetValue(HighlightedContentProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion Dependency Properties
    }
}
```

XAML resoure dictionary ImageButton.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:nqrgui="clr-namespace:NQR_GUI_WPF"
    >

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type nqrgui:ImageButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type nqrgui:ImageButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentControl
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                            x:Name="PART_Content"
                            />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter 
                                TargetName="PART_Content" 
                                Property="Content" 
                                Value="{Binding HighlightedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter 
                                TargetName="PART_Content" 
                                Property="Content" 
                                Value="{Binding ClickedContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                                />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here's how you'd use it:

```
<Window
    ...
    xmlns:nqrgui="clr-namespace:NQR_GUI_WPF"
    ...
    >

<!-- Or better yet, merge ImageButton.xaml in App.xaml so everybody can see it -->
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ImageButton.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

...

    <!-- As noted, Content, HighlightedContent, and ClickedContent 
    can be images -- or also paths, text, ANYTHING XAML can render.
    -->
    <nqrgui:ImageButton 
        Content="Content"
        HighlightedContent="Highlighted"
        ClickedContent="Clicked"
        />
```

And you really can go absolutely berserk with the content:

```
    <!-- Don't try this in a UI anybody will have to use! -->
    <nqrgui:ImageButton 
        Content="Content"
        ClickedContent="Clicked"
        >
        <nqrgui:ImageButton.HighlightedContent>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border 
                    BorderBrush="Gray" 
                    Background="GhostWhite" 
                    BorderThickness="1">
                    <Path 
                        Width="20" 
                        Height="20" 
                        Stroke="Black" 
                        StrokeThickness="2"
                        Data="M 0,0 L 20,20 M 0,20 L 20,0"
                        Margin="2"
                        />
                </Border>
                <nqrgui:ImageButton
                    Content="LOL"
                    ClickedContent="Don't Click Me, Bro!"
                    HighlightedContent="I heard you like buttons"
                    />
            </StackPanel>
        </nqrgui:ImageButton.HighlightedContent>
    </nqrgui:ImageButton>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the detailed answer. However, I encountered the following problems with your code: 
1. C#: "Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'ImageButton'" and "Partial declarations of 'ImageButton' must not specify different base classes", because VS automatically generates the following code in obj/Debug/ImageButton.g.i.cs: `public partial class ImageButton : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl, System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector`

2. XAML resource dictionary: member "IsPressed" not recognized or not accessible.
I am trying to make it work.

Comment: @CristianM If you delete `obj/Debug/ImageButton.g.i.cs`, does VS still re-create it? If so, try deleting all the old ImageButton files, root and branch, and creating it again with "New Class" and "New Resource Dictionary". Maybe with a slightly different name, just to be sure. The `IsPressed` issue may be that the lingering .g.i.cs file is declaring ImageButton as a subclass of `CustomControl`, which doesn't have `IsPressed`. Once it fully grasps that it's a Button subclass, `IsPressed` shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You're the best! It worked! One little question: what do I have to change in the style so "IsMouseOver" and "IsPressed" are triggered when mouse is over/clicks the grid, not the content, because, in this case, the events are triggered if I hover/click the icon lines.

Comment: Figure it out myself, eventually. I had to set `Background="Transparent"` for the Grid. Thanks again!

Comment: @CristianM oh right, yeah -- no mouse events from transparent stuff. That bites me once a week.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `TemplateParent` incorrectly

instead of this

```
{Binding Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}
```

it should be something like this

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
 AncestorType=ImageButton}, Path=Image}
```

Comment: I get the following error: "ImageButton is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project." It builds with AncestorType=Button, but the problem remains.

Comment: ImageButton is a popular name and may exist in other packages you are referencing. In your AncestorType use the fully qualified name (include namespace) to make sure it's using your version of ImageButton

Comment: I used AncestorType=NQR_GUI_WPF.ImageButton, but no success.

Comment: try AncestorType={x:Type=local:NQR_GUI_WPF.ImageButton}

Comment: I tried this "AncestorType={x:Type local:ImageButton}", to avoid "nested types" error, but still no success.

Comment: try AncestorType=UserControl

Comment: Tried, but the image is still not displayed. I really don't know why.

Comment: try removing the style triggers and have another go.

Comment: to be honest, youve kinda gone about it the wrong way. In your UserControl code-behind add event handlers to the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events and then change your content there. Remove all of the XAML inide the button

Answer (score 0):

I have done that like this below,

```
 <Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill"  x:Key="CloseImage" ImageSource="../images/Close.png" />
    <ImageBrush x:Key="CloseImageRed" ImageSource="../images/CloseRed.jpg" />
  </Controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

<Button>
       <Button.Style>
         <Style TargetType="Button">
           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CloseImageRed}"/>
           <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                      <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
               <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                 Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                 VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                 SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                 RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                      </Border>
                     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CloseImage}"/> 
                         </Trigger>
                     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>                                                    
  </Style>
 </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Have a look.

Comment: Thank you! Your code is useful for image button that uses actual images, not canvas. However, I will use a canvas, because the icon looks better.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `UserControl.Content` to your customized Button, and I think what you want to be setting is `UserControl.ContentTemplate`.

From within `.Content`, there is no "TemplatedParent" to bind to. However if this were a `Template`, then `TemplatedParent` would point to the `UserControl` that the Template is defined for. In this case, it would refer to your ImageButton UserControl, which would correctly give you access to the `Image` properties.

```
<UserControl ..>
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <!-- TemplatedParent bindings should refer to UserControl from here -->
            <Button ... /> 
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

This also allows you to write something like

```
<local:ImageButton Content="Some Text" />
```

without completely replacing your Button XAML code with a Text element containing "Some Text"

For an example, what you have right now would render as

```
<UserControl>
    <Button /> <!-- Button is .Content, and can be replaced by XAML using the control -->
</UserControl>
```

While if it were a ContentTemplate, it would render as

```
<UserControl>
    <Button> <!-- Button is ContentTemplate, so wraps any content given by external XAML -->
        <Content />
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```